# Create jar file from java file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, terminal

I have a java file with few classes.
I have tried to create jar file but it didn't work. I used eclipse and terminal (mac). For the terminal, I tried to use the command:

```
jar -cvf jar filename class file class file
```

I created that jar file but then it didn't work.

Please let me know what is the best way to create jar file.

Thank you

Comment: Define "didn't work"? What didn't? You created the jar file, then what happened?

Comment: Right click your project -> Export.. -> Java Folder -> Runnable Jar File -> Select the appropriate Launch Configuration -> Finish

Answer (score 2):

I believe that when you say it didnt work, what you mean is, you couldn't execute the packaged jar file that you created.

A jar file is little more than just a zip of all classes and resource files. You need to add details into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file so that the class containing the main method to be executed is know.

Alternately you can try invoking the jar file as follows:

```
java -cp <jarfile.jar> <Complete.Package.ClassNameWithMainMethod>
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what's not working, but here is the official documentation if it helps any: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html.